# Show only the content of the clicked card

Tags: reactjs

How can I only expand the area that I have clicked on?
I have already tried to pass the index of the map function into the handleExpandClick () function, but that didn't work either
For the moment, all cars are expanded if i click at one.

```
export default function Card({ wert, ergebnis }) {
 const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);


const handleExpandClick = () => {
  setExpanded(!expanded);
};

[...]

 {ergebnis.map((e, index) => (

 [...]

  <IconButton
    className={clsx(classes.expand, {[classes.expandOpen]: expanded,})}
    onClick={handleExpandClick}
    aria-expanded={expanded}
    aria-label="show more"
   >

  [...]

  <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>[...]</Collapse>

  [...]


  ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an object to track each elements expanded state, something like:

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState({});
const handleExpandClick = (index) => {
    setExpanded({
        ...expanded,
        [index]: !expanded[index]
    });
};

<IconButton
    className={clsx(classes.expand, {[classes.expandOpen]: !!expanded[index],})}
    onClick={() => handleExpandClick(index)}
    aria-expanded={expanded}
    aria-label="show more"
>

<Collapse in={!!expanded[index]} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>[...]</Collapse>
```